# failed to insert json from android into mysql

Tags: mysql, json

some help pliz.
my android app sends a json like

```
[{"userName":"fred","userId":"1"},{"userName":"juma","userId":"2"},     {"userName":"drer","userId":"3"},{"userName":"drer","userId":"4"},{"userName":"sdd","userId":"5"}]
```

to my php 5.3 server. When i use the string in code it works perfect after commenting out json_encode, but when i use file_get_contents it does nothing, when i uncomment json_encode it returns NULL.. what am i doin wrong. my server host is using php 5.3.28. this is my code..

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once './db_functions.php';
//Create Object for DB_Functions clas
$db = new DB_Functions(); 

//Get JSON posted by Android Application
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');


//$json ='[{"userName":"fred","userId":"1"},{"userName":"juma","userId":"2"},{"userName":"drer","userId":"3"},{"userName":"drer","userId":"4"},{"userName":"sdd","userId":"5"}]';

//$json = preg_replace("#(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|([\s\t](//).*)#", '', $json);

//$json = json_encode($json);     
$data = json_decode($json, true);

//Util arrays to create response JSON
$a=array();
$b=array();

//Loop through an Array and insert data read from JSON into MySQL DB
for($i=0; $i<count($data) ; $i++)
{

//Store User into MySQL DB
$res = $db->storeUser($data[$i]->userId, $data[$i]->userName);

    //Based on inserttion, create JSON response
    if($res){
        $b["id"] = $data[$i]->userId;
        $b["status"] = 'yes';
        array_push($a,$b);
    }else{
        $b["id"] = $data[$i]->userId;
        $b["status"] = 'no';
        array_push($a,$b);
    }
}
//Post JSON response back to Android Application
echo json_encode($a);


?>
```

the errors are...

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in XXXX on line 28    

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxxxxx on line 28

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in xxxxxx on line 28        

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxxxxx on line 28

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in xxxxx on line 32    

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xxxxx on line 32
[{"id":null,"status":"yes"}]
```

NB.. line 28 is

```
$res = $db->storeUser($data[$i]->userId, $data[$i]->userName);
```

and line 32 is

```
$b["id"] = $data[$i]->userId;
```

when i echo $json this is part of my logcat

```
    49-949/com.qnatz.ppolocations I/System.out﹕ [{"userName":"sorry","userId":"1"},{"userName":"wakeup","userId":"2"},{"userName":"sleeping","userId":"3"}]
02-13 12:32:17.110      949-949/com.qnatz.ppolocations W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-13 12:32:18.070      949-949/com.qnatz.ppolocations I/System.out﹕ usersJSON=%5B%7B%22userName%22%3A%22sorry%22%2C%22userId%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%7B%22userName%22%3A%22wakeup%22%2C%22userId%22%3A%222%22%7D%2C%7B%22userName%22%3A%22sleeping%22%2C%22userId%22%3A%223%22%7D%5D
02-13 12:32:18.100      949-949/com.qnatz.ppolocations W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value usersJSON of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
02-13 12:32:18.100      9
```

Comment: replace " with \" in your json encoded string. And one thing. Are you trying to insert the whole json to database?

Comment: the json come from android so contents are bound to change...thats why am using .....$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); So which line can i change and yes the whole json will be iterated into the database... thnx for the help

Comment: added this line but no change....$json = str_replace('"','\"', $json);

Comment: echo the $json from back to your android and see the log. Is it the same?

Comment: i updated my post with the echo $json.... its an invalid json... what can i do

Comment: How are you sending it to php from android? Can you paste the ansroid code too ?

Comment: thnx @SNt for the love...you pushed me into the right direction..... hope it helps some other guys

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT WITH THIS CODE...

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once './db_functions.php';
//Create Object for DB_Functions clas
$db = new DB_Functions(); 

//Get JSON posted by Android Application
//$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$json = urldecode(utf8_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['usersJSON'])));

//Remove Slashes
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
$json = stripslashes($json);
}

//Decode JSON into an Array
$data = json_decode($json);
//Util arrays to create response JSON
$a=array();
$b=array();
//Loop through an Array and insert data read from JSON into MySQL DB
for($i=0; $i<count($data) ; $i++)
{
//Store User into MySQL DB
$res = $db->storeUser($data[$i]->userId,$data[$i]->userName);
    //Based on inserttion, create JSON response
    if($res){
        $b["id"] = $data[$i]->userId;
        $b["status"] = 'yes';
        array_push($a,$b);
    }else{
        $b["id"] = $data[$i]->userId;
        $b["status"] = 'no';
        array_push($a,$b);
    }
}
//Post JSON response back to Android Application
echo json_encode($a);

?>
```